# How to get the last day of the month in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a spreadsheet with 100 worksheets (Year 1 to Year 100), each of which has a column containing numerical days (i.e., 1-365 or 366) and 3 columns of data which I will need to average by month. Is there a good way to quickly convert the days to date, and then calculate the monthly average using an Access query. Seems basic, but I could sure use the help.

[image]

Comment: "Seems basic" --- it is.  What have you tried so far? -- if we just tell you the answer then you don't understand the problem.  What have you tried?  Did you try something that did not work?  How could you use some help?

Comment: I have tried messing around with the EOMonth and AverageIFs functions in Excel. I am certainly able to perform the averages function with ease but I'm stuck on how getting the days in a usable format and somehow converting them to end of month when dealing with 100 years worth of data...

Comment: ok post what you have.  here is a hint -- to get the last day of the month, take the first day of the next month and substract 1 day

Answer (score 1):

The dates would be:

```vb
' SheetYear = 1 to 100
' RowDay = 1 to 365/366
RowDate = DateSerial(1900 + SheetYear, 1, Day)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a date and you want to get the last day of the month

D is a date

```
DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", 1, D)), Month(DateAdd("m", 1, D)), "1"))
```

We get the year and the month of the next month, then we make a date the first day of that month and then subtract 1 from it.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe that would work. I've started looking at the CDate function as well.  I'll let you know what I come up with.

Comment: With `DateSerial`, the 0th day of a month gives you the last day of the previous month.  `DateSerial(Year(D), Month(D) + 1, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is simple:

First day of month:
=DateSerial(Year(Date());Month(Date());1)

Last day of month:
=DateSerial(Year(Date());Month(Date());31)

Comment: Too much simple. Last day will not run on febrary, april, etc.. It could be DateSerial(Year(Date());Month(Date())+1;0)